# IBRS not enabled

Tags: security

On my computer with ubuntu 16.04 the spectre-meltdown-checker gives this output:

```
Spectre and Meltdown mitigation detection tool v0.37+

Checking for vulnerabilities on current system
Kernel is Linux 4.4.0-122-generic #146-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 23 15:34:04 UTC 2018 x86_64
CPU is Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU  N3150  @ 1.60GHz

Hardware check
* Hardware support (CPU microcode) for mitigation techniques
  * Indirect Branch Restricted Speculation (IBRS)
    * SPEC_CTRL MSR is available:  YES 
    * CPU indicates IBRS capability:  YES  (SPEC_CTRL feature bit)
  * Indirect Branch Prediction Barrier (IBPB)
    * PRED_CMD MSR is available:  YES 
    * CPU indicates IBPB capability:  YES  (SPEC_CTRL feature bit)
  * Single Thread Indirect Branch Predictors (STIBP)
    * SPEC_CTRL MSR is available:  YES 
    * CPU indicates STIBP capability:  YES  (Intel STIBP feature bit)
  * Enhanced IBRS (IBRS_ALL)
    * CPU indicates ARCH_CAPABILITIES MSR availability:  NO 
    * ARCH_CAPABILITIES MSR advertises IBRS_ALL capability:  NO 
  * CPU explicitly indicates not being vulnerable to Meltdown (RDCL_NO):  NO 
  * CPU microcode is known to cause stability problems:  NO  (model 76 stepping 3 ucode 0x367 cpuid 0x406c3)
* CPU vulnerability to the three speculative execution attack variants
  * Vulnerable to Variant 1:  YES 
  * Vulnerable to Variant 2:  YES 
  * Vulnerable to Variant 3:  YES 

CVE-2017-5753 [bounds check bypass] aka 'Spectre Variant 1'
* Mitigated according to the /sys interface:  YES  (Mitigation: OSB (observable speculation barrier, Intel v6))
* Kernel has array_index_mask_nospec (x86):  NO 
* Kernel has the Red Hat/Ubuntu patch:  YES 
* Kernel has mask_nospec64 (arm):  NO 
> STATUS:  NOT VULNERABLE  (Mitigation: OSB (observable speculation barrier, Intel v6))

CVE-2017-5715 [branch target injection] aka 'Spectre Variant 2'
* Mitigated according to the /sys interface:  YES  (Mitigation: Full generic retpoline, IBPB (Intel v4))
* Mitigation 1
  * Kernel is compiled with IBRS support:  YES 
    * IBRS enabled and active:  YES  (for both kernel and user space)
  * Kernel is compiled with IBPB support:  YES 
    * IBPB enabled and active:  YES 
* Mitigation 2
  * Kernel has branch predictor hardening (arm):  NO 
  * Kernel compiled with retpoline option:  YES 
    * Kernel compiled with a retpoline-aware compiler:  YES  (kernel reports full retpoline compilation)
> STATUS:  NOT VULNERABLE  (Full retpoline + IBPB are mitigating the vulnerability)

CVE-2017-5754 [rogue data cache load] aka 'Meltdown' aka 'Variant 3'
* Mitigated according to the /sys interface:  YES  (Mitigation: PTI)
* Kernel supports Page Table Isolation (PTI):  YES 
  * PTI enabled and active:  YES 
  * Reduced performance impact of PTI:  NO  (PCID/INVPCID not supported, performance impact of PTI will be significant)
* Running as a Xen PV DomU:  NO 
> STATUS:  NOT VULNERABLE  (Mitigation: PTI)

A false sense of security is worse than no security at all, see --disclaimer
```

The microcode update supports IBRS but it is not enabled by default (but can be enabled, see answer). Instead retpoline with IBPB is used for mitigation. Why is it so? Would be IBRS not a better protection as retpoline, because IBRS protects also the user space? How can i force the kernel to use IBRS?

Comment: Try getting the latest version of the [script][1] . The output of mine is slightly different which means something has changed. Post the new results if differents.

  [1]: https://github.com/speed47/spectre-meltdown-checker

Comment: I updated now the script to the latest version. In the question is now the latest output, now with ibrs enabled.

Answer (score 0):

See the [spectreAndMeltdown/MitigationControls](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/SpectreAndMeltdown/MitigationControls) wiki on this subject

At run time:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/ibrs_enabled
```

will turn off IBRS

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/ibrs_enabled
```

will turn on IBRS in kernel

```
echo 2 > /proc/sys/kernel/ibrs_enabled
```

will turn on IBRS in both userspace and kernel.

To inspect the change use

```
sysctl -a|grep ibrs
```

All done after doing `sudo -i` and not using normal `sudo`.

Then check if your reporting tool is updated.

But why do anything at all? Media has blown this way out of proportion and there needs to be a lot more wrong with your system for anyone to be able to abuse this. Common sense should prevail over paranoia.

Comment: Thank you for your information. I enabled now ibrs and posted the output in the question.  But even if ibrs is enabled the kernel will choose retpoline for mitigation and not ibrs ...

Comment: @isndw I know it's late but do you have at the command line: *`spectre_v2=retpoline`*? If so my guess is that's why. CentOS defaults to that now but oddly the script in question in OP reports that v2 is vulnerable still. Various things on the GitHub repo as well as RH BZ suggest it's an issue with the script but I don't know. However in an older Fedora install (server upgrade with new choices meant I went for a new CentOS install) it does not have that option at the kernel command line and the script reports it's not vulnerable. Which makes me wonder if it's an issue with the script after all.